# Adverbial use of そんな without に

Tags: grammar

What puzzles me are these two sentences (coming from *Ensemble Stars!!*, both spoken by teenage characters and unrelated to each other):

> んもう。**そんな**睨まないでくださいってば〜。絶対悪いようにしませんから

> あっ。**そんな**適当に拭っちゃダメよォ！ バイ菌が入ったらどうするの！(about another character's wounded ear)

In both of these そんな seems to be used adverbially ("don't wipe [the blood] off *so* carelessly", "please don't glare at me *like that*" ("*so much*"?)) and so I'd expect it to be followed by に, like in this example sentence from Tatoeba, for instance:

> 彼女のことで**そんなに**真剣に悩む必要はなかったのに。

But, well, it clearly isn't, and I haven't been able to find information about this kind of use of it online. Are those language errors or is something else at play here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In formal Japanese, yes, そんな is attributive (i.e., modifies a noun) and そんなに is adverbial (modifies a verb or an adjective). However, in very informal speech, そんな can work adverbially, too. そんな睨まないでください and そんな**に**睨まないでください are interchangeable, but the former sounds much more colloquial (or perhaps slightly childish). This type of adverbial そんな should be avoided in business settings.

Your examples happen to be used with negation, but it can also be used with non-negative verbs. For example, you can say そんな心配なら電話して, そんな走ったら危ないよ and so on.

I have looked at several dictionaries and websites, but none of them mention this directly.